# Retrieving score value when using presentModalViewController to switch views in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, presentmodalviewcontroller

I face this problem of retrieving a game "highscore" after someone finishes a game.

What I did was this:

I call presentModalViewController method when time reaches 0.

```
GameEndingViewController *gameEndingView = [[GameEndingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameEndingViewController" bundle:nil];
gameEndingView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:gameEndingView animated:YES];
[gameEndingView release];
```

I want to show the score that I attained in the main gameloop in this gameEndingView that I have. However, it seems that when I use presentModalViewController method to switch view. The variable, score, that I update during the gameloop gets reseted. My whole game loop is in a view gameMainView.

Could someone explain to me about the use of presentModalViewController and how should I better solve my problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: In your current controller hierarchy, the **score** var belongs to which controller?

Comment: the score var belongs to mainViewController.

Comment: so what i did was when viewdidload for GameEndingViewController, I go through appDelegate to retrieve the score var in mainViewController which returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the problem with your modal view. You have a problem in the app logic. You should better check this out again.
The good idea would be declaring the score as the property and set a breakpoint so you could see where it is changed.

Comment: I'm really sorry about this as I am pretty new to programming. What you mean by declaring score as the property. Does that mean that I do use @property int score for the variable in mainViewController? It looks to be changing properly in the mainViewController.

Comment: Yep. And set a breakpoint at the line with @synthesize score. Then rewrite every part, where you are accessing the score like a variable to access via property: score  --->  self.score (if inside the controller)  and   objName.score if you do that outside.

Comment: and make sure you're not killing your mainviewcontroller and creating it once again...

Comment: so when i call presentmodalviewcontroller to bring up gameEndViewController, it does not kill the mainViewController?

Comment: no it doesn't. i mean check your whole code, to be sure that everything works correctly